# nodejs Worker_Threads with expressjs just spawn one worker

Tags: node.js, express

i wrote example code for Worker_Thread in nodejs
my Worker code :

```
const {
    Worker, isMainThread, parentPort
} = require('worker_threads');

if (isMainThread) {

    module.exports.func=()=>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let worker = new Worker(__filename);
            worker.on('message', resolve);
            worker.on('error', reject);
            worker.on('exit', (code) => {
                if (code !== 0)
                    reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
            });
        });

}
} else {
    const s = new Date().getSeconds();
    while (true) {
        if (new Date().getSeconds() - s >= 5) {
            console.log("its Done after 5 sec")
            parentPort.postMessage('its Done')
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

so when run in in other file its fine spawn worker for each call 
for example :

```
const {func}  = require('./workerFile');
func().then()
func().then()
```

its execute two time and same time!!!

but when i used Expressjs
its wont work :

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
 func().then(()=>{
     res.send('Result')
 }).catch((e)=>{
     res.send('err')
 })       
})
```

its just spwan one worker for '/' route and wait untill done and can request route again
{other route are Not blocked}

so how can i fix it i want spawn worker for each request to '/'

tnx for Reading <3